# docker-compose.yaml won't parse

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

I am having trouble with running my docker-compose.yml. I have retrieved a pre-made docker-compose file from a github page and customized it to my needs. When trying to parse it, it returns errors.

I am not very schooled in yaml syntax, so it is difficult for me to understand where the error stems from.

The code from the docker-compose.yml file is posted on this pastebin: https://pastebin.com/XjM2S11i

The following errors are returned when parsing:

```
ERROR:

while parsing a block mapping
  in "<unicode string>", line 5, column 1:
    version: "3.6"
    ^
expected <block end>, but found '<block mapping start>'
  in "<unicode string>", line 149, column 3:
      watchtower:
      ^
```

Can anyone help me fix the syntax/indentation? Would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your file you have (line 115):

```
phpmyadmin:
    hostname: phpmyadmin
```

So the value for the key `phpmyadmin` of your root level mapping is a mapping itself which starts of with a key `hostname` which is indented **four** positions.

Then on line 149 you have:

```
  watchtower:
    container_name: watchtower
```

which is only indented two positions. You'll have to decide what is the parent node of `watchtower`: either it is a key for the root level mapping and then it needs to be flush left or it is a key in the same mapping that `hostname` is a key in and then it needs to be indented four positions. Or that there needs to be a key inserted at the root level mapping before `watchtower`.

I strongly recommend always to use number of **two positions** indentation for both mapping values and sequence items (and that implies **no** offset for the sequence item indicator):

```
a:
  b:
  - 1
  - 2
```

Your docker-compose YAML file is a hodgepodge of at least 2 and 4 position indentation for mappings and 2, 3  and 4 position indentation for sequence items.

That docker-compose hasn't complained about:

```
ports:
 - "80:80"
  - "443:443"
```

in your file yet is unexpected, as it is **not** valid YAML.

Answer (score 1):

'Lint' (syntax check) the docker-compose.yml using something http://www.yamllint.com/, correct the syntax errors, then re-run the Docker command.

Comment: I know of that website, but I am not sure how to correct the mistakes

Comment: The backend for that site is the ruby parser, which differs in some details from the PyYAML (Python) library that docker-compose is using.